# Why is SQL query returning Parse error: ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, sqlite

I get

> Parse error: ambiguous column name: ratings.rating

Why is that happening? I named all columns from which table they should come from...

```
SELECT 
    movies.title, ratings.rating 
FROM 
    movies, ratings 
JOIN 
    ratings ON movies.id = ratings.movie_id 
WHERE 
    movies.year = 2010 
ORDER BY 
    ratings.rating DESC, movies.title;
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this excerpt:

```
FROM movies, ratings
JOIN ratings
```

This includes two separate instances of the `ratings` table, which is allowed, but without any alias to distinguish between them, which causes an error.

We can fix this by removing the `,ratings`:

```
FROM movies
JOIN ratings
```

FWIW, the `A,B` join syntax has been obsolete for 30 years now, and should no longer be used for new development. Especially don't mix it in the same query with the newer `A JOIN B` syntax, as it leads to mistakes like this.

Additionally, it is a good practice to use short mnemonic aliases for your tables, even if you don't think you'll need them:

```
SELECT m.title, r.rating 
FROM  movies m
JOIN ratings r ON m.id = r.movie_id 
WHERE  m.year = 2010 
ORDER BY r.rating DESC, m.title;
```

Comment: Also, the original query's ON clause has no access to the movies table, since explicit JOIN's are evaluated before implicit, comma separated ones.

Comment: @jarlh Does this mean that JOIN should came before FROM?

Comment: @Mihael, no, I'm just pointing out another problem with your query. But do what Joel says, stick to explicit JOIN syntax.

Comment: Oh I get it now maybe. I could do something like this: 
SELECT m.title, r.rating 
FROM  movies m, ratings r 
WHERE m.id = r.movie_id AND  m.year = 2010 
ORDER BY r.rating DESC, m.title;

Comment: You _could_ do that, but you should not. Again, that syntax has been obsolete for _30 years_.